# How to find a document based on an array element with a mongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a Document with the following structure:

```
order: {
    id: 1,
    items: {[
        {id: 0
        type: ‘string’},
        {id: 123
        type: ‘string’}
    ]}
}
```

I would like to write a query that can find me an order that has an `‘items’`, with an id of 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your collection is called orders, using `$elemMatch` on the items array key should allow you to search by id in the nested document

```
db.orders.find({items: {$elemMatch: {id:0}}});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think

```
db.orders.find({"items.id": 0});
```

should work.